# Quick Explanation of fail

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and I am having difficulty in understanding the way of which, `fail` works.

I have a simple code below and I enter into the query  I get the false result:

```
?- f1(X).
 false.
```

---

```
a(1).
a(2).
a(3).
a(4).
a(5).

b(2).
b(3).
b(4).
b(5).

c(3).
c(4).
c(5).

d(4).
d(5).

f1(X):-  a(X),!, fail, b(X).
f1(X):-  d(X).
```

But if the f1(X) was defined like:

```
f1(X):-  a(X), b(X), fail.
f1(X):-  d(X).
```

And the output of the same query would be:

```
 X = 4 ;
 X = 5.
```

Could anyone explain how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fail` is always `false`, there is nothing more to it. I think you should think about how backtracking and `!` work.

First code with cut works that way:

- `?- f1(X)` is expanded into `?- a(X),!, fail, b(X)`
- `a(X)` is found to be true for `1`
- then, there is a `!` which means that `a(1),!, fail, b(1)` is being cut to `?- fail, b(1)` **and that any other clause of `f1/1` won't be checked** (eg. `d(X)` won't be queried)
- `fail, b(1)` is always `false` because `fail` is always `false`

And your second code:

- `?- a(X), b(X), fail.` is always `false` because `fail` is always `false`
- first clause is `false` **so we try another clause**
- `?- d(X).` is true for `4` and `5`.